# Stop Audio Clip/ Audiosource

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I have a very long audio clip that should start playing when a certain condition is met (1st IF in the code below) and keep playing until another condition is met (2nd IF).

The problem is I can't figure how to make the audioclip stop playing, I tried audio.Stop() but it says there is n definition for Stop(), can you help?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PowerShutdown: MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioClip[] on_sfx;
    int i;
    int k;

    void Start () 
        {
        k = 1; 
        }

    void Update () 
        {
        if (PlayLevel1.percentageLoadProductionint < 100 && StateManager.activeState is PlayState && Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > 1 && k== 1) 
            {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (on_sfx [0], transform.position);
            k = 2;
            }

        if (PlayLevel1.percentageLoadProductionint > 100 && StateManager.activeState is PlayState && Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > 1 && k == 2)
            {
            audio.Stop ();
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (on_sfx [1], transform.position);
            k = 1;
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to call `Stop` on the audio source. Better not use `PlayClipAtPoint` (see answer from NewDeveloper), but another play function and a gamobject with a audiosource attached.

Comment: Unity tells to use this instead GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop ();

Comment: But it does not work because there is no Audiosource attached to the PowerShutdown object.

Comment: Yes, because `PlayClipAtPoint` creates a audiosource at the point where you want to play the audio (see below answer). If you use another play function, you need an audiosource attached to something that you use to play the clip.

Comment: `PlayClipAtPoint` is meant for short sound effects like when a bullet hits something etc.

Comment: Do you advise on another playing method?

Comment: Just use `Play()`. Have a look at the docs here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because "PlayClipAtPoint" is a static method and the stop method is going to have issues with it due to a referencing error.  From reading the docs it says "This function creates an audio source but automatically disposes of it once the clip has finished playing."

This means that a new "AudioSource" is created at the 3D space specified to play the requested audio.  Meaning that, either you need a reference to the new audio source (*unsure how you would do that*), or use a different play method.

Comment: Do you advise on another playing method?

Comment: I would use Play on your audioSource and then Stop on it when you're done with the current audio clip